# How to map to array instead of object

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a `map` below

```
map(x => ({
  name: 'Name',
  series: []
})),
```

that returns an Object `{name: "Platform", series: Array(10)}` but what I need is an array `[{name: "Platform", series: Array(10)}]`

How would you do that?

Comment: Just add some `[` ... `]`s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main ways you could approach that problem
first being simply putting object into array and returning it the shortened way

```
map(x => [{
    name: 'Name',
    series: []
  }]
)
```

and second being returning the array with a return statement in case you need some additional functionality in there

```
map(x => {
  //additional functionality here
  return [{
    name: 'Name',
    series: []
  }]
})
```